# Открыть URL в C++

Tags: c++, linux

**Снова здравствуйте!**

Просьба подсказать мне, как можно наиболее быстрым образом передать обработчику на сервере некие данные, находящиеся в GET-запросе? Подчеркну, что **наиболее быстрым и удобным**. Да, и еще, забыл уточнить один из ключевых моментов: это должно выполняться под Linux.

Answer (score 3):

**Наиболее быстрым и удобным**

```
system("wget ...");
```

нет?

Answer (score 3):

Создаешь соккет, соединяешься с нужным ip:port, посылаешь `GET /<имя файла>?<данные запроса>\r\n\r\n`. Отключаешься.

Варианты под винду и линукс ничем не отличаются. Только include разные. Пример писать лень, их полно в интернете.

Answer (score 2):

Ну можно и по другому

```
 cat >/dev/tcp/YouServer/ServerPort
 GET <ваш запрос> HTTP/1.0<enter>
 <enter>
 <ctrl-D>
```

Ну про nc/ncat и говорить не стоит